# Debug Flask app in Pycharm with odd structure

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I'm new to debugging flask with pycharm, so hopefully nothing I ask is too trivial.

I have two files, `code/__init__.py` and `code/runserver.py`.

The `__init__.py` file is where my Flask app is initialized, meaning that is where the statement

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

occurs.

In the `runserver.py` file is where I have the statement:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The runserver imports the app in the following manner:

```
from code import app, __app_name__, __version__
```

Inside of the main function are a number of `parser.addoption` commands and then ultimately

```
def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-d", "--debug", action="store_true",
                      default=app.config.get('DEBUG', True),
                      dest="debug", help="Turn on debugging")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    app.run(debug=options.debug, host=options.address, port=options.port)
```

In this case what would my entry point for debugging the application be?
I assumed it would be `runserver.py` but when I attempt to debug this I get the response of

```
ImportError: No module named code
```

If however I run it like

```
python ${BASE}/code/runserver.py
```

I don't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Several moments

1) If you want to debug with PyCharm you should set default debugger to False (app.debug)
2) In PyCharm you should not use /code/ folder as root, because in this manner no code is visible by import
If you make codeProject/code/ and open codeProject as root in pycharm and then run codeProject/runserver.py or codeProject/code/runserver.py everything should be fine